# Why do I get an ImportError exception when importing np_utils from karas.utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2, os
from glob import glob
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K
```

I'm trying to import the following modules and packages. But I'm facing this error, saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\KUNDANA\Desktop\rama\DSA- Python\trails.py", line 13, in <module>
    from keras.utils import np_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'np_utils' from 'keras.utils' (C:\Users\KUNDANA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to one hot encode the targets of the data in advance. Please use the code:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

instead of the line:

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
```

and the problem resolves.